# How do you put multiple lists in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am in the middle of solving some practice problems.

Q. Make a list that looks like this:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

So I first made a list that has three two-element lists like below.

```py
    a = []
    for i in range(3):
        line = []
        for j in range(2):
           line.append(0)
        a.append(line)
    print(a)
```

```
    >>> [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
```

Then I was trying to change the elements into 1-6, but I am struggling at this part.

Could someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the practice problem. Why can't you just write `a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`? As for your question, do you know how to index? e.g. `a[0][0]`? It would help if you posted your best attempt. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your code this:

```
a = []
for i in range(1,7,2):
    line = [i, i+1]
    a.append(line)

print(a)

>>> [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] # Yay!
```

1st line, `a = []`: Just makes an empty list

2nd line, `for i in range(1,7,2)`: What that does is go through range 1-7, skip counting by 2. That gives you 1, 3, and ends at 5.

3rd line, `line = [i, i+1]`: That just gives you either `line = [1,2]`,`line = [3,4]`, and `line = [5,6]`. Very basic.

4th line, `a.append(line)`: Adds list line to list a.

5th line, `print(a)`: Prints the output.

Or even better:

```
a = [[i,i+1] for i in range(1,7,2)] # 1 line of code!
print(a)

>>> [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] # Yay!
```

That is called a list comprehension. I recommend looking at a few websites like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is why I wanted to learn python. There is always a better way. And I'll make sure I look at the website you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 1
a = []
for i in range(3):
    line = []
    for j in range(2):
       line.append(num)
       num = num + 1
    a.append(line)
print(a)

>>> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for this.

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)
a = [[next(counter) for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)]
print(a)  # -> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: P.s. based on the question you seem like you're just starting, so I'm happy to add an explanation if you need

Comment: Just like you assumed, this is way higher level than my current capability, but thank you anyways for your kind reply :)